# Java rounding double to arbitrary number (9)

Tags: java, rounding

I'm trying to make a calculator that will add two numbers and double them then take the doubled value and round it UP to the nearest nine. i have been unable to figure out how to make it always round up to the nearest 9. so 13.33 should become 19.00 or 19 or can even read 19.99 if it HAD too i can just disregard that pennies.

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: I don't understand... you say it should round up to the nearest `9`, yet you say that stuff can round up to `19.99`, which is not a "nearest 9" ("nearest 9" implying that it is an integer).

Comment: 13.33 should become 19 or 19.99 ??

Comment: it should always round up and always to 9 so like for a pricing structure. so if i buy the item for 6 dollars the code doubles the price to 12 then rounds it up to 19. so i can have a quoted price of 19. or then if i enter a 65 dollar item it doubles to 130 then up to 139.

Answer (score 1):

I think this will do it:

```
 x = (int)Math.ceil((n1 + n2) * 2)
 x = x + (9 - (x % 10))
```

Comment: please add multiply by 2 and round up

Comment: these seems to work for most instances however i just did 19.99 and 4.99 which comes out to 49.96 after the doubling and then it generated 49 is there a way to fix that?

Comment: updated the code to do the doubling, and cast to an int

Comment: the code and the doubled version both seem to work for most instances unless the generated value is 9.01-9.99 then it wants to round to the lower 9

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
double x = 4.99;
double y = 6.99;
double z = x + y;
float xFloat;

z = z * 2;
xFloat = (float)Math.ceil(z);
xFloat = xFloat + (9 - xFloat % 10);
System.out.print(xFloat);
```